# Jenkins Robot Test Plugin failed to Load "browse results" page

Tags: jenkins

I have added the RobotPublisher plugin into the Jenkins

```
                step(
                        [
                                $class              : 'RobotPublisher',
                                outputPath          : 'run/docker/log',
                                outputFileName      : '**/output.xml',
                                reportFileName      : '**/report.html',
                                logFileName         : '**/log.html',
                                disableArchiveOutput: false,
                                passThreshold       : 90,
                                unstableThreshold   : 70,
                                otherFiles          : "**/*.png,**/*.jpg",
                        ]
                )
                pass_number=getTestCaseNumber("pass").toInteger()
                fail_number=getTestCaseNumber("fail").toInteger()
                total=pass_number+fail_number
            }
```

And in the previous 40+ builds, **I can click the "Browse results" button on the Jenkins job page and the page is working fine**.

However, start from some job (just the same as previous jobs), I can never load the "Browse results" page anymore. It's saying "page took too long to respond.".

I wonder is it something file cache-related since we ran the test job every day and the log report keeps cached and never cleared? Does a Jenkins restart help? How can I further debug? Any help, please!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally I found the cause. For my Jenkins job, I keep 40 builds total and it each job will have around 3.4MB log size. So, during the job goes, the space is got limit and the latest job was not able to store the logs so that it can't load the page.

So the way to fix this is to reduce the number of builds, e.g. to 10 now. And it works perfectly in my Jenkins.